# Pandas Series - print columns and rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scipy

For now I am not so worried about the most performant way to get at my data in a series, lets say that my series is as follows :

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
```

If I am using a for loop to iterate this, for example :

```
for row in seriesObj:
    print row
```

The code above will print the values down the right hand side, but lets say, I want to get at the left column (indexes) how might I do that?

All help greatly appreciated, I am very new to pandas and am having some teething problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Series.iteritems](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html).

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=iter('ABCD'))

for ind, val in s.iteritems():
    print ind, val
```

Prints:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

Comment: Ah cool, thanks, and how might I then decide to get the index alone each time or the value?

Like, say I wanted to have

key = row_key
data = row_data

Comment: Thankyou - I will try this later and will be sure to update the best answer when I get home :)

Comment: @Slippy please accept the answer (click the check mark next to the answer) if it answered your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I have been so damn busy with work this week that I forgot to sign in - your help has been greatly appreciated.