# Printing Matrix of dataset into Table using Pandas with single column transposed

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, numpy

I'm using Movie Lens [Dataset](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip) in Python Pandas. I need to print the matrix of `u.data` a tab separated file in foll. way

```
NULL    MovieID1 MovieID2 MovieID3
UserID1 Rating   Rating   Rating
UserID2 Rating   Rating   Rating
```

I've already been through following links

1. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356270/pandas-series-print-columns-and-rows#) - Dataset is much huge put it in series
2. [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842066/python-pandas-certain-columns-to-rows) - Transpose of Row not mentioned
3. [Three](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) - Tried with reindex so as
   to get NaN values in one column
4. [Four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394598/select-specific-csv-columns-filtering-python-pandas) - `df.iloc` and `df.ix`
   didn't work either

I need the output so as it shows me rating and NaN (when not rated) for movies w.r.t. users.

```
    NULL    MovieID1 MovieID2 MovieID3
    UserID1 Rating   Rating   NaN
    UserID2 Rating   NaN      Rating
```

P.S. I won't mind having solutions with numpy, crab, recsys, csv or any other python package

**EDIT 1 - Sorted the data and exported but got an additional field**

```
df2 = df.sort_values(['UserID','MovieID'])
print type(df2)
df2.to_csv("sorted.csv")
print df2
```

The file produces foll. *sorted.csv* file

```
,UserID,MovieID,Rating,TimeStamp
32236,1,1,5,874965758
23171,1,2,3,876893171
83307,1,3,4,878542960
62631,1,4,3,876893119
47638,1,5,3,889751712
5533,1,6,5,887431973
70539,1,7,4,875071561
31650,1,8,1,875072484
20175,1,9,5,878543541
13542,1,10,3,875693118
```

**EDIT 2 - As asked in Comments**

Here's the format of Data in u.data file which acts as input

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
298 474 4   884182806
115 265 2   881171488
253 465 5   891628467
305 451 3   886324817
```

Comment: Would paste a sample of the input data in the question?

Comment: @ScottBoston please check the edit 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method:

Use pivot_table and if one value per user and movie id then aggfunc doesn't matter, however if there are multiple values, the choose your aggregation.

```
df.pivot_table(values='Rating',index='UserID',columns='MovieID', aggfunc='mean')
```

Second method (no duplicate userid, movieid records):

```
df.set_index(['UserID','MovieID'])['Rating'].unstack()
```

Third method (no duplicate userid, movieid records):

```
df.pivot(index='UserID',columns='MovieID',values='Rating')
```

Fourth method (like the first you can choose your aggregation method):

```
df.groupby(['UserID','MovieID'])['Rating'].mean().unstack()
```

Output:

```
MovieID  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
UserID                                         
1         5   3   4   3   3   5   4   1   5   3
```